# Flutter showing an abnormal behaviour when it comes to foreground from background

Tags: android, ios, flutter

When my app comes from the background to the foreground .It starts showing abnormal behaviour. It pings my server 100 times  and then crashes. I didn't get any information from crashlytic also. It doesn't happens everytime instead only happens some time. I was able to extract the crash log. Here it is

```
End time:         2020-08-22 00:22:53 -0400
OS Version:       iPhone OS 13.6 (Build 17G68)
Architecture:     arm64
Report Version:   29
Incident Identifier: 59186B12-DA1E-40E8-83BC-1510B9E3B752

Data Source:      Microstackshots
Shared Cache:     0x35b84000 59A390C7-D5F2-3C2D-991C-2F90FE9A5180

Command:          Livecart
Path:             /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F61FDA5F-F436-4C43-A0EA-25B5CF398A63/Livecart.app/Livecart
Version:          ??? (???)
PID:              50400

Event:            wakeups
Action taken:     none
Wakeups:          45001 wakeups over the last 139 seconds (324 wakeups per second average), exceeding limit of 150 wakeups per second over 300 seconds
Wakeups limit:    45000
Limit duration:   300s
Wakeups caused:   45001
Wakeups duration: 139s
Duration:         138.90s
Duration Sampled: 130.74s
Steps:            29

Hardware model:   iPhone10,6
Active cpus:      6
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this @Jawad Ahmed?